# How can I access table field data in web.py template

Tags: python, web.py

I'm using web.py, and I make a general data view template, like this, results is a db query result, columns is a list contain columns name:

```
$def with(results,columns)
$var title:All data

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
$for f in columns:
    <th>$f</th>    
</thead>
<tbody>
$for r in results:
    <tr>
    $for f in columns:
        <td>$r.$f</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>    
</table>  
<hr />
```

The table's head is shown good,but the table data always shown this:

```
<Storage {'remark': u'', 'cid': 32, 'created': datetime.date(2016, 5, 23), 'id': 2}>.id
```

How can I show the table's data?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$for f in columns:
    <td>$r[f]</td>
```

rather than `$r.$f`.

Examine your output example and note that you're seeing indeed the value of `$r` (the full row) followed by a period, followed by the value of `$f`, "id" in this case.

Templates are a bit tricky, but think "once you've entered python realm, you don't further escape variables with $."  So here, visualize it as `$(r[f])`, though `$r[f]` is completely legitimate.